# Encoding Error in android SMTP Email send

Tags: android, utf-8, smtp

i want to send email with SMTP in android. but when email send, it has encoding problem. in English there is no problem but in Perisan character i recive in email is "?" for each character. part of my code is:

```
String emailBody = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText5))
                        .getText().toString();
                new SendMailTask(SendMailActivity.this).execute(fromEmail,
                        fromPassword, toEmailList, emailSubject, emailBody);
```

Comment: You could try `URLEncoder.encode(emailBody, "UTF-8");`

Comment: It does't work!

Comment: There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with SMTP.

Comment: @saeidmirzapour Are you putting it inside of the excecute? You may also want to do it for the subject.

`new SendMailTask(SendMailActivity.this).execute(fromEmail, fromPassword, toEmailList, URLEncoder.encode(emailSubject, "UTF-8"), URLEncoder.encode(emailBody, "UTF-8"));`